# How to expand/collapse accordion tab when clicking a button?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have this accordion, so in order to **expand/collapse** an accordion tab I click anywhere on the tab, but I want to be able to expand/collapse when clicking **ONLY** on the **"Click me" button** and not on the accordion tab. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-yajmjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<p-accordionTab header="Accordion Tab 1" [selected]="true">
   <p-header>
      Accordion Tab 1
      <span>
         <button (click)="myFunction($event)">Click me</button>
      </span>
  </p-header>
   <ul>
     <li>Colors</li>
   </ul>
</p-accordionTab>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion) for the accordion component that you're using, you can use the **Programmatic Control** to implement what you need.

Here is the [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-3lwtd2), where I modified your code. All tabs are disabled and they are opened/closed programmatically **only by clicking on the "Click me" buttons** in their headers.

---

**UPD** new [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-1kjkjx) with:

- `multiple="true"`
- has all tabs open by default
- custom styling that overwrites the `disabled` property

Comment: I don't want to disable all accordion-tabs and I still want to use [multiple]="true"  at the accordion level just like I have it on my code

Comment: @progx You can use [multiple]="true" as per docs with this solution: 
"Tabs can be controlled programmatically using activeIndex property, in single mode it should be a number and in multiple mode an array of numbers that define the indexes of active tabs."

Comment: Your solution doesn't work with [multiple]="true" and I want to keep all tabs open

Comment: @progx I've updated the answer to include the solution that has:
1. all tabs open by default
2. uses multiple="true"
3. has custom styling that overwrites the disabled prop

Comment: @your answer throws an error in the console when expanding an accordion tab a little fast. Here's the error: AccordionTab.html:12 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ui-accordion-content-wrapper-overflown: true'. Current value: 'ui-accordion-content-wrapper-overflown: false'.

Comment: Add `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` after the `this.indexes = [ ...this.indexes ];`

Comment: @ritaj what is changeDetectorRef? how do I declare it in the class? Can you please share a working Demo? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just Google it, it's a core part of Angular, you will find a lot of examples

Comment: @ritaj I already google it and its still not clear to me. How do I declare changeDetectorRef in the class? What part of the accordion do I target with that?

Comment: I mean it's all in the documentation. https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef Also don't target anything, just type `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` after `this.indexes = [ ...this.indexes ];`

Answer (score 0):

css File:-

```
.zippy{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius:2px;
}
.zippy-heading{
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #f09b9b;
}
.zippy-body{
 padding: 20px;
}
.expanded{
 background: #b3b0b0;
}
```

Html view:-

```
<div class="zippy" style="padding:40px;">
  <div class="zippy-heading"
    [class.expanded]="isExpandedBikes"
    (click)="onBikeClick()">
    {{bike}}
    <span
      class="fa"
      [class.fa-angle-down] ="!isExpandedBikes"
      [class.fa-angle-up]="isExpandedBikes"
      (click)="onBikeClick()" style="font-size: 20px; position: absolute;right: 50px;"></span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isExpandedBikes" class="zippy-body">
    <li *ngFor ="let data of bikeContent">
      {{data}}
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component File:-

```
constructor() { 
 this.bike = "Bikes";
 this.bikeContent=["My First Bike","My Second Bike","My Third Bike"];
}
```

for button Fxn in component File:-

```
 onBikeClick(){
  this.isExpandedBikes =! this.isExpandedBikes;
 }
```